# Automate testing with out installing anything on client machine

Tags: automation, qtp

We have a requirement to automate testing on website with out installing anything on client machine(including with out running driver in client),
I have gone through grid model in selinum, but there we need to run webdriver on client machine which I can't do.
So, I need suggestions how can I automate web site with out installing or running jar or dll  on client machine.
I am looking for any possibility injection of automation script from server machine to client.

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement that nothing be installed? Do you mean that nothing can be installed by a privileged user? I would approach this by using a Linux machine, and install Webdriver in the same dir where you place your test executable(s). There's no need to install webdriver as root. The same should be true on Windows if you use the C# webdriver bindings and write your tests in C# (although I'm partial to Python!)

Answer (score 0):

Try Sikuli Automation tool.

you don't need to install sikuli application in your client machine.

Import sikuli libs with java program - http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/030-java-dev.html

Export your program as executable jar and use it in your client machine